# How deny direct access for uploaded js files in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I used File Manager and uploaded some txt and js files which is not part of site.
I denied access to site from refers except one.
Files can be read using browser.

I created folder and put these txt and js files,added htaccess and wrote next code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://allowed refer site/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ - [F]
```

However txt and js can be opened using browser.

```
<FilesMatch ~ "\.(txt|js)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This code didn't effect,files are still can be read.
All files have chmod 600.How close access to these files to all refers except one?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct access"? If such files should not be accessible, store the uploads somewhere outside your public directory

Comment: "direct access" means "i can type in browser address site.com/folder/file js or txt and i can read this file,but access must be denied because rule for specific refer only"

Comment: I changed chmod to 000 and now direct access to file denied with 403 error.Chmod to 400(only owner can read) give direct access.It seems htacess think that user is owner which read file.

Comment: Both those rule blocks would block access. (Although the first rule blocks `.css` files, not `.txt` files.) Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled for this subdirectory in the server config? Do you have any other directives? Any other `.htaccess` files?